# Dynamically Reference Another Worksheet in "pivot_table" Argument of GETPIVOTDATA Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When reading data from another worksheet, is there is a way to have the "pivot_table" Argument reference a variable cell instead being hard coded to the target worksheet/pivot table?
Existing Formula:

=GETPIVOTDATA("Message ID",'Intake Inventory Pivots'!$B$2,"Queue Desc",R4,"Role Desc",C4)

I would like this argument to be a cell reference to cell S4: 'Intake Inventory Pivots'!$B$2

This would allow me to specify the source pivot table in said cell reference.  Each row of my table needs to point to a different pivot table, so having a cell reference would allow me to fill the GetPivotData formula down without having to manually update the GetPivotData formula in each row.
I have tried concatenated versions of that argument and tried referencing a named range, without any success.

TIA

Attempted Formulas that have failed:

=GETPIVOTDATA("Message ID",S4,"Queue Desc",R4,"Role Desc",C4)
contents of S4:  ''Intake Inventory Pivots'!$B$2 or 'Intake Inventory Pivots'!$B$2

=GETPIVOTDATA("Message ID","'"&S4&"'!$B$2","Queue Desc",R4,"Role Desc",C4)
contents of S4:  Intake Inventory Pivots

=GETPIVOTDATA("Message ID",S4&"!$B$2,"Queue Desc",R4,"Role Desc",C4)
contents of S4:  ''Intake Inventory Pivots' or 'Intake Inventory Pivots'

=GETPIVOTDATA("Message ID",S4,"Queue Desc",R4,"Role Desc",C4)
contents of S4:  Intake_Inventory_Pivot  (this one is a named range that refers to 'Intake Inventory Pivots'!$B$2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indirect formula works, as advised by BigBen:

=GETPIVOTDATA("Message ID",INDIRECT("'"&S4&"'!$B$2"),"Queue Desc",R4,"Role Desc",C4)
contents of S4: Intake Inventory Pivots